# Best Java Datastructure to store key Value Pair

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)
>   [Bi-directional Map in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java)

I want a `key value data structure` to use for Android App. I can use `Map<K,V>`, but in `Map` I can't get key for particular Value.

Is there any good Java data structure using which I can retrieve key by value and vice-versa.

Comment: Look at Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: You could just implement a small method to do so; it will be 4 lines of code; instead of using any third party.

Comment: @Deepak it is better to use well-tested and widely accepted libraries for such a general use case. You will avoid a lot of pain.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup

Comment: Second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Map with entrySet and Map.Entry class to iterate and get both keys and values even if you don't know any of the keys in the Map.

```
Map <Integer,String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer,String> pairs = (Map.Entry<Integer,String>)iterator.next();
    String value =  pairs.getValue();
    Integer key = pairs.getKey();
    System.out.println(key +"--->"+value);
}
```

Comment: Sure, this will work. But it will be slower and slower with growing number of entries. He's better of with a `BiMap`

Comment: But He need not to put a new jar file and make his app heavy, And I don't find any much significant change in performance.

Comment: Do you prefer an app that get's slower over time, or an app that is (a tiny little bit) bigger when downloading initially?

Comment: Depends...

Also bi map will maintain two maps and internally and not allow me to duplicate value

Comment: which makes total sense: If you had duplicate values, which key would you choose for an inverse lookup?? That's what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Guava [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

How to use Guava Libraris in Android is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925236/using-google-guava-with-android-1-6)

Answer (score 0):

[The best data structure would be Java HashMaps check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)  you can use the `get(Object key)` method